# How to use tf.lookup tables with TensorFlow 2.0 keras and MLFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lookup-tables

I spend the last 5 hours or so trying to get TF 2.0 keras API working with the tf.lookup API. My training script also uses DataBricks and `mlflow.keras`. MLFlow requires that the model be serialized, which I think is what is causing issues for me. The question is: how to use tf.lookup tables with TensorFlow 2.0 keras Model API and MLFlow.

I was getting keras issues with serialization when trying to use the functional Keras API with table.lookup directly:

```
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(vocab_path, tf.string, 0, tf.int64, 1, delimiter=","), 1)
categorical_indices = table.lookup(categorical_input)
```

Wrapping the above call in a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` layer didn't help.
I was getting errors related to resource handles or missing `tf` variable...

Comment: This isn't really a question, is it ? Consider editing your post to include only a well formulated question and feel free to post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sharing the solution here to save somebody else some pain. This the solution that I found to work:

```
vocab_path = os.path.join(mount_point, 'category_vocab.csv')

class VocabLookup(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, vocab_path, num_oov_buckets, **kwargs):
    self.vocab_path = vocab_path
    self.num_oov_buckets = num_oov_buckets
    super(VocabLookup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):

    vocab_initializer = tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(
      self.vocab_path, tf.string, 0, tf.int64, 1, delimiter=",")
    self.table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(vocab_initializer, self.num_oov_buckets)

    self.built = True

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.table.lookup(inputs)

  def get_config(self):
    return {'vocab_path': self.vocab_path, 'num_oov_buckets': self.num_oov_buckets}

lookup_table = VocabLookup(vocab_path, 1)

categorical_indices = lookup_table(categorical_input)
```

Basically, don't use layers.Lambda if you are referring to any outside variables (include tf or tensorflow module). For example, this doesn't work for me:

```
def reduce_sum(x):
  return tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)

embedding_sum = layers.Lambda(reduce_sum)

categorical_features = embedding_sum(categorical_embeddings)
```

But this works:

```
class ReduceSum(layers.Layer):
  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=1)

embedding_sum = ReduceSum()
categorical_features = embedding_sum(categorical_embeddings)
```

The `layers.Lambda` doesn't seem to like upvalues.